# Realization/embedding for (weakly) finite linear categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

I am trying to determine the status of the following claim. I know how to prove this (unless I made a stupid mistake), so the question is mostly

- Is it in the literature?
- If not, is there something similar that could be useful?

Any comments would be very helpful. Thanks!

---

Let C be a linear category over a field k (that is, an abelian category enriched over k-spaces). Suppose that it satisfies the following finiteness relations:

1. C is essentially small
2. Every object of C has finite length
3. All hom spaces are finite-dimensional.

**Claim.** C is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional modules over a pro-finite-dimensional k-algebra.

Here a *pro-finite-dimensional k-algebra* is a filtered projective limit of finite-dimensional k-algebras, or in more classical terms, a topological k-algebra that is complete and whose topology has a basis given by two-sided ideals of finite codimension. And of course, the modules must agree with this structure (i.e., they are topological).

**Background.** If we assume in addition that C has finitely many simple objects (up to isomorphism) and enough projectives, this becomes a known statement. Such categories are called *finite (abelian) categories*, and the claim is that C is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional representations of a finite-dimensional algebra. (By the way, the statement is attributed to Deligne on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+abelian+category); do you know the source of this attribution? The reference on nLab is to a paper by Etingof and Ostrik, which as far as I see simply gives the statement.)

Comment: This can fail due to size considerations; a necessary condition for this to be true is that $C$ must have a set of simple objects. As a counterexample, take $C$ to be the category of finite-dimensional ordinal-graded vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks, of course I assume that C is essentially small (forgot to put it in the question, now corrected).

Comment: First, apparently http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4204 contains a proof of the background statement you cite. Second, can you sketch the proof you have in mind? I have a strategy in mind but I don't know how to make it work with the given hypotheses (although I'm not sure what more hypotheses are needed).

Comment: Thanks for the reference! (Still wondering why the claim was attributed to Deligne...) I will be happy to discuss the statement/proof, but I'd rather do it over email if you don't mind --- it's easier to just send the file.